# What does this sentence mean: "don't keep giving jazz"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning, american-english

Few days back, I was communicating with a friend, and she is much better at English than me.

There came a situation where I tried to be like I was not knowing anything and asked her something. And she replied like, "I know you know the answer."

Then after few minutes one more text was there like **"don't keep giving jazz"** but still I can't get what this last text message was meant to be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [jazz](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/jazz?s=t)
>   5. *Slang.* insincere, exaggerated, or pretentious talk:
>   *Don't give me any of that jazz about your great job!*

Assuming she is talking about you and the answer, we can interpret it in a few ways:

> 1. Don't be insincere.
> 2. Don't act/play dumb.
> 3. Don't pretend like you don't know the answer.

She wants you to be serious and give her the answer.

By the way, as in the dictionary entry, it would sound better with "me":

> Don't keep giving **me** jazz.